# Flexbox image gallery with diffrent sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve this effect on gallery https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMkXW.jpg , but Im keep getting this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j3YT.jpg

**Important thing to note that Im only allowed to use flexbox with flex-direction: column, aslo I cannot change size of every image manualy and every image is 500px wide**

Here is the code `of html

```html
    <section class="gallery">

       <div> <img src="images/3.jpg"> </div>

       <div> <img src="images/1.jpg"> </div>

       <div>  <img src="images/2.jpg"></div>

       <div> <img src="images/5.jpg"></div>

       <div> <img src="images/4.jpg"> </div>

    </section>
```

`And here is from css

```html
.gallery {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    align-items: center;
    height: 1018px;
    width: 620px;
}

.gallery img {    
    flex: 1 1 50%;


}

.gallery img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

It feels like I'm missing some very important stuff about flexbox, so any explanations or direction what should I do, is welcome.

**Edit**: The whole "site" looks like this https://i.imgur.com/p18zuRG.png and it can look good only on desktop. There's no need for mobile view.

Comment: are the heights of the images fixed as well?

Comment: This would be done easier with CSS grid, as opposed to CSS flexbox. You can learn more about CSS grid here >>> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_grid_responsive.asp

Comment: You could try adding `max-width: 50%;` to your images to limit them from getting as large as they are. It is hard to tell since we can not use your images to test this ourselves.

Comment: also, why did you set your gallery width to 620px if your image widths were 500px at the least?

Comment: Is it just this set of images you are required to layout? If not, do you know anything about the images apart from the width being 500px or are you trying to set up a general-purpose two column masonry layout which will work however many images  there are and of whatever aspect ratio they are?

Comment: I added Edit with image how site looks like.
@ProsyArceno I thought that will not allow images to went to sides.

Answer (score 1):

Outcome you are wanting is in portrait mode, but most probably you are working on a device suited for landscape viewing...

I have made a outline of flex boxes you might want to have a look at, all you have do is insert the images in each box.

Note. you can change the width of the main block in respect to the the viewport.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Centaur26/pen/JjWKNRx)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    
    html,
    body {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    
    .main {
      display: flex;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px dashed red;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    .main .left {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .left .a {
      display: flex;
      width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      border: 1px dashed black;
    }
    
    .left .b {
      width: 100%;
      height: 25%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .left .c {
      width: 100%;
      height: 25%;
      border: 1px solid green;
    }
    
    .main .right {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      width: 50%;
      height: 100%;
      border: 2px dashed yellow;
    }
    
    .right .a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 60%;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
    .right .b {
      width: 100%;
      height: 40%;
      border: 2px dotted red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="left">
      <div class="a">divA</div>
      <div class="b">divB</div>
      <div class="c">divC</div>
    </div>

    <div class="right">
      <div class="a"></div>
      <div class="b"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution is almost perfect, the only issue is, that left column is now larger by one image ( how it looks https://i.imgur.com/swCjt4d.jpg ). This should only look good on desktops.

Comment: @jernej, could you post the whole screenshot of the outcome and also code you are using, hard to see from half a picture to see whats not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}



.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.gallery {
  -ms-flex: 25%; /* IE10 */
  flex: 25%;
  max-width: 25%;
  padding: 0 4px;
}

.gallery img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .gallery {
    -ms-flex: 50%;
    flex: 50%;
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .gallery {
    -ms-flex: 100%;
    flex: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

.gallery img {
        flex: 1 1 50%;
      }

.gallery img:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}
</style>
<body>

<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">

  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/850x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/450x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
  </div>  
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/500x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
  </div>
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/800x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/350x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/300x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/550x400/000/fff" style="width:100%">
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```